# Using AVPlayer to play DRM protected songs

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

For various reasons I need to use AVPlayer to play music from the IOS iTunes library.  When I try to retrieve the URL for a DRM protected song the result is null.  Has anyone found a way to achieve this?

Comment: Looked in apple devforums, don't seems to have a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish this, period. The only supported way to play the DRM-protected songs is via the built-in library. You also can't record that stream, it gets mixed in at a different stage to prevent apps from getting the DRM music that way.

Comment: Doesn't seem doable from AVPlayer or AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Could not play using avaudioplayer or avplayer.